# Michael Fassbender's Steve Jobs reference to Seth Rogen's Wozniak as "Rain Man"

Tags: dialogue, steve-jobs

In the movie *[Steve Jobs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_Jobs_(film))* by Danny Boyle, we see a conversation between Jobs and John Sculley immediately before the launch of NeXT (if I remember correctly).
(picked from [wikiquote](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Steve_Jobs_(2015_film)))

> John Sculley: You're gonna end me, aren't you?
>
> Steve Jobs: You're being ridiculous...I'm gonna sit center court and watch you do it yourself. Then I’m gonna order a nice meal with a ‘55 Margaux, and sign some autographs.
>
> John Sculley: Jesus Christ.
>
> Steve Jobs: You want some advice, Pepsi Generation? Don’t send Woz out to slap me around in the press. Anybody else.You, Markkula, Arthur Rock, **anyone but 'Rain Man'**. Don’t manipulate him like that. Whatever you may think, I’m always gonna protect him.

Why does Jobs refer to Wozniak as 'Rain Man' here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In *Rain Man* (1988), Dustin Hoffman's titular character is a genius suffering from autism and thus has no social skills to survive normally in the world full of lies and deceptions. Even his brother plans to exploit his gullibility for selfish reasons but eventually then starts caring for him shielding him from the people that might exploit him to benefit from his geniuses.

Jobs was drawing the analogy between the complicated relationships of the brothers in Rainman Movie and the one Jobs had with Wozniak and also an analogy between the misunderstood motives Rainman's brother and Jobs.